# Обработка пользовательских исключений

Tags: c#

Имеет ли смысл так обрабатывать пользовательские исключения:

```
public void MainMethod()
{
    try
    {
        SomeMethod();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new MainMethodException("Main method exception", ex);
    }
}

public void SomeMethod()
{
    // NoDataException and NoConfigException can be thrown
}

public class NoDataException : ApplicationException { }

public class NoConfigException : ApplicationException { }

public class MainMethodException : ApplicationException
{
    public MainMethodException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
}
```

Исключения пустые, но носят самоописательные названия. Дело в том, что в `catch(Exception ex)` вне зависимости от типа исключения происходит приведение к базовому типу `Exception`. Или лучше для каждого типа исключения писать свой `catch` блоки и свой `throw new MainMethodException`?

Comment: Приводятся к базовому и являются базовыми - это разные вещи. Несмотря на "базовость" это не база а я бы сказал "интерфейс взаимодействия", в зависимости от того как обработчик "пережует" вы можете менять 1)МеssageText (как короткое сообщение) так и 2) ToString() метод (длинное сообщение об ошибке). А ещё вы можете 3)ваш тип исключения (или группу типов) отбирать в catch(YourException)

Comment: Из Exception всегда можно получить ваш тип исключения. Например так `if (inner is YourException)  (inner as YourException).Message`;

Comment: Кастомные исключения нужны для того, что бы можно было собрать больше информации об ошибке. Например SqlException может посмотреть какую ошибку вернула база, и вычитать у драйвера СУБД подробности ошибки. Например, если хотите сообщение об ошибке на разных языках, или по коду ошибки брать её текст. Или, например, что бы отделить один вид исключений от других в catch.

Comment: `catch(Exception ex)` не всегда сработает для исключения отличного от Exception. Например тут `catch (MathException) {} catch (Exception) {}`.

Comment: @nick_n_a спасибо за разъяснения, это всё понятно. Здесь шла речь о рациональности использования пустых классов исключений с самоописательными именами

Comment: это рационально, если вы хотите один вид исключений гарантировано отделить от других. Предыдущий пример показывает как.

Comment: @nick_n_a Если обрабатывать эти пустые исключения одним catch блоком с последующим throw тоже приемлемо (т.к. есть возможность приведения обратно к конкретному типу исключения), то вопрос можно закрывать